# AngularJS dropdown conditions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dropdown, interaction

1. Change 2nd dropdown from "Sauces" to "Dairy"

   Change 1st dropdown "D - Full List" to "A - Partial List"

   Show 2nd dropdown "Select..." and keep 3rd dropdown the default value "Ice"

In simple words, show "select..." in 2nd or 3rd option if user switches from "Full List" to "Partial List" as the selected option is available in full list but not in partial list.  But if user chooses an option that is available in both full and partial list, do not switch to "select..." and keep the option value as is.

I have added if () statement for the scope values. It is not working.  The 2nd and 3nd dropdowns are empty instead of showing "select..." I am hardcoding 'undefined' which is far from ideal and how do I set it up so it works for all scenarios and any number of values?

Lastly, I need to return the values back to the user.

Plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/twzFtMVv5ZDRJ1BHaqWo?p=preview)

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module("prototype", []);

app.controller("Controller", function($scope) {
 $scope.myDropDown = 'aisleD';
 $scope.full1 = 'Sauces';
 $scope.full2 = 'Ice';
 
  $scope.onChanged = function() {
  
 
 //How do you elegantly mock this interaction up in AngularJS?
$scope.partial1 = $scope.full1;
 if($scope.partial1 == 'undefined:undefined'){
 $scope.partial1 = 'select'
 }
 else
    {
 $scope.partial1 = $scope.full1;
 }
 
$scope.partial2 = $scope.full2;
 if($scope.partial2 == 'undefined:undefined'){
 $scope.partial2 = 'select'
 }
 else
    {
 $scope.partial2 = $scope.full2;
 }
 
 
  
  
  
 }
});
```

```css
#timeFrameAndMeasures .InputField{float:left;width:auto;margin-right:20px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.0" data-semver="1.2.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body ng-app="prototype">
    <div id="timeFrameAndMeasures" ng-controller="Controller">
      <div class="InputField">
        <select class="InputField-select InputField-input--withIconButton" ng-model="myDropDown" ng-change="onChanged()">
          <option value="aisleA">A - Partial List</option>
          <option value="aisleB">B - Partial List</option>
          <option value="aisleC">C - Partial List</option>
          <option value="aisleD">D - Full List</option>
          <option value="aisleE">E - Full List</option>
          <option value="aisleF">F - Full list</option>
        </select>
      
      </div>
      
      <!--1st measure partial list-->
      <div class="InputField" ng-show="myDropDown=='aisleA' || myDropDown=='aisleB' || myDropDown=='aisleC'">
        <select class="InputField-select InputField-input--withIconButton" ng-model="partial1">
          <option value="select">Select...</option>
          <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
          <option value="Ice">Ice</option>
          <option value="Sauces">Sauces</option>
        </select>
       
      </div>
      <!--end 1st measure partial list-->
      <!--2nd measure partial list-->
      <div class="InputField" ng-show="myDropDown=='aisleA' || myDropDown=='aisleB' || myDropDown=='aisleC'">
        <select class="InputField-select InputField-input--withIconButton" ng-model="partial2">
          <option value="select">Select...</option>
          <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
          <option value="Ice">Ice</option>
          <option value="Sauces">Sauces</option>
        </select>
       
      </div>
      <!--end 2nd measure partial list-->
      <!--1st measure full list-->
      <div class="InputField" ng-show="myDropDown=='aisleD' || myDropDown=='aisleE' || myDropDown=='aisleF' || myDropDown=='custom'" ng-hide="myDropDown=='aisleA' || myDropDown=='aisleB' || myDropDown=='aisleC'">
        <select class="InputField-select InputField-input--withIconButton" ng-model="full1" ng-change="onChanged()">
          <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
          <option value="Dairy">Dairy</option>
          <option value="Ice">Ice</option>
          <option value="Magazines">Magazines</option>
          <option value="Meats">Meats</option>
          <option value="Pantry">Pantry Staples</option>
          <option value="Sauces">Sauces</option>
          <option value="spice">Spice</option>
        </select>
     
      </div>
      <!--end 1st measure-->
      <!--2nd measure full list-->
      <div class="InputField" ng-show="myDropDown=='aisleD' || myDropDown=='aisleE' || myDropDown=='aisleF' || myDropDown=='custom'" ng-hide="myDropDown=='aisleA' || myDropDown=='aisleB' || myDropDown=='aisleC'">
        <select class="InputField-select InputField-input--withIconButton" ng-model="full2" ng-change="onChanged()">
          <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
          <option value="Dairy">Dairy</option>
          <option value="Ice">Ice</option>
          <option value="Magazines">Magazines</option>
          <option value="Meats">Meats</option>
          <option value="Pantry">Pantry Staples</option>
          <option value="Sauces">Sauces</option>
          <option value="spice">Spice</option>
        </select>
     
      </div>
      <!--end 2nd measure-->
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Here we expect you to have a go at your problem yourself before coming to us for help. Do that, and then edit your question and write in the code you've got so far (even if it isn't working).

Comment: Thank you.  I wrote the code I've got so far and it is not working.  A newbie with AngularJS with a jquery mindset, this is all very exciting but challenging.  Thank you for all of your pointers.